# Simple administrator area?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I want to make an administrator page for my website. It will be very simple - some fields that report various database statistics, and some tools to allow the administrator to rename certain categories in a simpler way than writing out sql queries.

Obviously, this page needs to be secure. I want to keep it separate from the login system that regular users on the site use - it could just be a "enter username + password" prompt that appears when sometime tries to access the page.

What is a secure way to do this? Or is this even secure at all?

Comment: which mechanism you use for other users to login?

Comment: Forms authentication I think. I'm not very familiar with the way authentication works in asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your web-app through `Form-based` authentication & authorization. You may  define different `roles`  so you can `grant` or `deny` access to a given resource based on that *roles* in the Application.

Read these articles:

1. [Using Forms Authentication in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150650/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.shtml)
2. [How To Implement Forms-Based Authentication in Your ASP.NET Application by Using C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240)
3. [Building Custom Providers for ASP.NET 2.0 Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx)
4. [An Overview of Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb)

Answer (score 0):

you can have a separate folder admin with in the web contents and inside that you create this page. This has to be a username and password page for admin which can then navigate you to a page where you can do/decide what ever the admin wants to do.